# Use of Omittance vs Omission

Tags: meaning, word-choice, tenses

In writing a paper in a Microsoft Word Document I wrote "omittance," which prompted an edit remark from the program telling me that I spelled the word incorrectly. I don't know why I felt like writing omittance when I know that the proper word is omission, but there it was on the page. And honestly the word looked like it **should** be a word considering I wanted to use omission in a future tense. In Google searching I found the use of omittance in the unabridged Merriam Webster dictionary; however I hesitate to accept anything from them. So I ask the experts here, is omittance ever an acceptable tense of omission or should I omit its use forevermore?

Comment: I've probably seen "omittance" used a half-dozen times in my lifetime, but I can't think of any context where I'd be tempted to use it.

Comment: "omittance" is not a tense of "omission." Both are nouns, and nouns don't have tenses. They're just separate words, and "omission" is more common than the other. More generally, I do not know of a single "-mittance" word that is more common than its counterpart in "-mission." Unless a particular "-mittance" word has a specialized meaning (like *transmittance*) I would advise always using the "-mission" word.

Comment: I will note that the "-tance" word ending is fairly common in physics and techie jargon, and hence someone immersed in such jargon would find that form in some ways more comfortable.  I don't believe that it's so common among the general public, however.

Comment: To gain admittance vs to be given admission?

Comment: @sumelic although omission is a noun, omit is a verb. The instance of omission requires action, which is what prompted my desire to state, "It would be an unnecessary omittance on their part." Omission, of course, is the proper tense of omit in this instance.

Comment: I'm with @sumelic that nouns don't have tenses, but even supposing you were trying to say something about the tense of *omit*, how are you suggesting that "future tense" would make a difference? Omissions are for the past and omittances are for the future?

Comment: @JohnY Omissions would have worked (and is the correct use) in either instance. I'm not trying to argue that omittance should be used, but only explaining why my brain decided to tell my fingers to write omittance instead of omission. It's in the same context as stating that I will gain admittance later (or get admitted, but that sounds like I'm crazy), opposed to saying I gained admission earlier.

Comment: OK, then it seems to me you have a misunderstanding of the relationship between *admission* and *admittance*. Neither word implies anything whatsoever about the tense of *admit*. *Admission* is the broader term, encompassing both figurative and physical entry; while *admittance* implies physical entry. It's almost always fine to use *admission* in place of *admittance*. If you're thinking you gain permission to enroll at a university before you gain physical entry to that university, you've latched onto an incidental circumstance of the usage of the terms, not part of their meaning.

Comment: @JohnY Thank you, I did not know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omittance), *omittance* is an **obsolete** form of *omission*. The graph shown in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/omittance) supports this:

[image]

And while the entry in [OLED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/omittance) does not include such qualification, it's worth noting that it's omitted entirely from NOAD.

Comment: Great graph. I didn't know Merriam Webster's site had anything like that.

Comment: It's from Collins, not Merriam Webster. And Google has https://books.google.com/ngrams.

Answer (score -3):

There's no such word as 'omittance'. Omit should be more than adequate.

-ance describes a quality or state or an instance of one: arrogance, relevance.
or it can be used to describe an action. By its very definition an omission has no quality or state. Why are you trying to define the quality or state of an omission?

Comment: So a word might not be omitted several times, and one might not want to discuss a particular instance of the word being omitted?

Comment: And how does this explanation work with *remittance*? It's not a quality or a state; it's money.

Comment: @HotLicks As I stated in the comment above to Sumelic, the word omit is a verb. Omission might be a noun, but it is a result of when someone omits something.

Comment: yes, money has a quality and a state.

Comment: Various dictionaries, doubtless after their panels have checked and deliberated, say that 'omittance' is a word. I wouldn't use it myself, but I'm not qualified to decide on matters of  'wordness'.

Comment: @PeterShor - I am not endorsing this answer by any means, but it does say "or it can be used to describe an action", which in the case of *remittance* would of course be *remit*. But then it would seem to also apply to *omittance* (for *omit*), yet the answer seems to be trying to *deny* the validity of *omittance*. So yeah, I find this answer confusing at best.